# Upload error to Rpubs from R markdown Error in rawToChar(response$headers) : argument 'x' must be a raw vector

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to publish an RMarkdown file to RPubs using rsconnect.

The file knits to HTML appropriately on my Macbook. When I try to publish the knitted HTML to RPubs, I get the following error:

`Error in rawToChar(response$headers) : argument 'x' must be a raw vector`

I am able to publish other RMarkdown documents to RPubs. I tried setting options(rpubs.upload.method = “internal”) in a local .Rprofile file but this didn't help. I have removed any special characters from the headers in the .Rmd file so that they are just plain text but didn't help.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

`sessionInfo()` below:

````
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8/C/en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

other attached packages:
[1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2 pheatmap_1.0.12 factoextra_1.0.7 FactoMineR_2.3 gridExtra_2.3
[6] mgcv_1.8-31 nlme_3.1-147 gpairs_1.3.3 scales_1.1.1 kableExtra_1.1.0
[11] knitr_1.28 cmprsk_2.2-9 cowplot_1.0.0 survminer_0.4.6 survival_3.1-12
[16] lmerTest_3.1-2 wesanderson_0.3.6 PredictABEL_1.2-4 DescTools_0.99.35 lmtest_0.9-37
[21] zoo_1.8-8 lme4_1.1-23 Matrix_1.2-18 MASS_7.3-51.6 ggfortify_0.4.10
[26] GGally_1.5.0 ggrepel_0.8.2 ggsci_2.9 rstatix_0.6.0 ggpubr_0.3.0
[31] broom_0.5.6 forcats_0.5.0 stringr_1.4.0 dplyr_0.8.5 purrr_0.3.4
[36] readr_1.3.1 tidyr_1.1.0 tibble_3.0.1 ggplot2_3.3.0 tidyverse_1.3.0
[41] readxl_1.3.1 rsconnect_0.8.16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] minqa_1.2.4 colorspace_1.4-1 ggsignif_0.6.0 ellipsis_0.3.1 rio_0.5.16
[6] htmlTable_1.13.3 base64enc_0.1-3 fs_1.4.1 rstudioapi_0.11 farver_2.0.3
[11] PBSmodelling_2.68.8 fansi_0.4.1 mvtnorm_1.1-0 lubridate_1.7.8 xml2_1.3.2
[16] leaps_3.1 splines_4.0.0 Formula_1.2-3 jsonlite_1.6.1 nloptr_1.2.2.1
[21] km.ci_0.5-2 cluster_2.1.0 dbplyr_1.4.3 png_0.1-7 compiler_4.0.0
[26] httr_1.4.1 backports_1.1.7 assertthat_0.2.1 cli_2.0.2 acepack_1.4.1
[31] htmltools_0.4.0 tools_4.0.0 gtable_0.3.0 glue_1.4.1 Rcpp_1.0.4.6
[36] carData_3.0-3 cellranger_1.1.0 vctrs_0.3.0 xfun_0.14 openxlsx_4.1.5
[41] rvest_0.3.5 lifecycle_0.2.0 statmod_1.4.34 XML_3.99-0.3 barcode_1.1
[46] hms_0.5.3 expm_0.999-4 curl_4.3 KMsurv_0.1-5 rpart_4.1-15
[51] reshape_0.8.8 latticeExtra_0.6-29 stringi_1.4.6 checkmate_2.0.0 boot_1.3-25
[56] zip_2.0.4 rlang_0.4.6 pkgconfig_2.0.3 evaluate_0.14 lattice_0.20-41
[61] ROCR_1.0-11 labeling_0.3 htmlwidgets_1.5.1 tidyselect_1.1.0 plyr_1.8.6
[66] magrittr_1.5 R6_2.4.1 generics_0.0.2 Hmisc_4.4-0 DBI_1.1.0
[71] pillar_1.4.4 haven_2.2.0 foreign_0.8-79 withr_2.2.0 scatterplot3d_0.3-41
[76] abind_1.4-5 nnet_7.3-14 modelr_0.1.8 crayon_1.3.4 car_3.0-7
[81] survMisc_0.5.5 rmarkdown_2.3 jpeg_0.1-8.1 grid_4.0.0 data.table_1.12.8
[86] flashClust_1.01-2 vcd_1.4-7 webshot_0.5.2 reprex_0.3.0 digest_0.6.25
[91] xtable_1.8-4 numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 munsell_0.5.0 viridisLite_0.3.0 tcltk_4.0.0
[96] fortunes_1.5-4```
````

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this error and found a solution! In my case, the error was caused by issues with image file formats. Perhaps this line of reasoning will work for others. In my case, I found that the error would only arise if my R Markdown document included a code chunk with a call to

`knitr::include_graphics("Theory.png")`

I found that if I opened the file 'Theory.png' in Photoshop or Preview, and then exported a version in .jpg format, that resolved the issue. I then updated my call to 'include_graphics' and referenced the new .jpg file. That eliminated the

`rawToChar(response$headers) : argument 'x' must be a raw vector`

Error. This seems like a bug in either rsconnect or the RPubs back-end code, not sure. Here are the details of my system in case this helps trace the source of this bug.

`R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] rsconnect_0.8.16`

Comment: Any reason for you to use an old version of R?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge! This is my old office computer that went dormant when COVID-19 hit, and is just now coming back into use. I need to update the R!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I encounter this error even when not including graphics in my RMarkdown documents, ie only generating plots from within R. Any further suggestions greatly appreciated.